# Undefined reference to vtable in qt despite defing all my functions except the signal?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qt-creator

I am aware that this error usually occurs due to the parent class having a virtual function and that virtual function not being defined in the subclass.

I have , to my knowledge at least defined all the functions bar the function that is supposed to be the signal.

This the .h file for the class

```cpp
#ifndef HREAD_H
#define HREAD_H
#include "package.h"
#include <QThread>
class hread:public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void transfer(structureData* pkg);
public:
    hread();
   virtual ~hread();

private:
    structureData Send;

    bool abort,restart;
protected:
    void run() override;
};

#endif // INPUTTHREAD_H
```

This is my main .cpp file

```cpp
hread::hread()
{
 MutexSend.lock();
 restart=false;
 abort=false;
 MutexSend.unlock();
}

hread::~hread()
{

}

void hread::run()
{

    emit transfer(&pkg);

}
```

I can't quite pinpoint why I got this error.

Comment: Double check: is the `.o` for your source file mentioned in the link command?

Comment: what is the .o file and where can I find it

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos Please just post the compiler command (or commands) used to build your program.  Then we can comment on them.  Please add this information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: I hope this edit should be fine

Comment: @PaulSanders I used an IDE i didnt really use compiler commands

Comment: Thanks for the update.  As you can see from the error messages, the problem is with class `InputThread`, that's all I can tell you from the code posted.

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah my uni thinks putting code on public repositories is cheating

Comment: can we take this to private chat

Comment: The line starting with `g++` is the link command. It pulls in the object files for your sources named `main`, `window`, `recvvwindow`, `outputthread`, `inputthread`, `moc_window`, `moc_recieverWindow`, and `moc_outputthread`. If your implementation of `InputThread::transferPackageToRecieve()` is not in one of these sources, that is likely the reason for the undefined references.

Comment: @JaMiT transferPackageToRecieve () is a signal, arent signals meant to be defined by the MOC or something also I called it transfer in this code

Comment: From the commands posted you might be using the command 'make' I believe QT requires you use 'qmake' to generate the MOC files https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html

Comment: @jkengineeringworkvideos That might be (I'd have to look up the QT documentation), but one of those error messages is saying that the signal is not being defined. Get that signal properly generated (even if you don't need to supply the code for it), and the vtable will probably appear. (Kieran might have just saved me a read through the QT documentation.)

Comment: Guys I cleaned it and the issue went away, cos it prolly deleted the old moc and made a new moc which defined my signal